# AspNetCore webAPI Email Confirmation without IEmailSender

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I'm currently making a website in AspNetCore MVC and Angular/TypeScript.
Authentication fully works, with bearer tokens, using the Identity from AspNet itself.

**This is where my problem is:**
I want to now implement email confirmation in my AspNetCore webAPI.
Every single tutorial I've found bases itself on AspNet.Identity while I'm using AspNet**Core**.Identity.
The latter does not have the IEmailSender interface and a lot of other functionality that these tutorials use.
I've tried and search for specific tutorials but can not seem to find any.
If anyone has specific links or useful info to point me in the right direction that would really help as I think I might be mixing up a lot of different concepts.

Answer (score 0):

The base sample, which is a part of [AspNetCore sample MVC application](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/e6f3ebf5810c793edc6f3b4ca3438194786b86a2/samples/IdentitySample.Mvc/Controllers/AccountController.cs) (created using VS2017 project template) contains an implementation of email notifications (without a real sender). Besides, there is a good article with examples on in [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?tabs=aspnetcore2x%2Csql-server) .

Comment: I've tried following that tutorial, but they use AspNet.Identity which contains the `IEmailSender` interface for example. This does not exist on AspNetCore.Identity.

Comment: EmailSender in this tutorials isn't a part of MS Identity. Take a look at scaffolded controllers after installing AspNetCore.Identity. I have posted a link to gitHub (https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/e6f3ebf5810c793edc6f3b4ca3438194786b86a2/samples/IdentitySample.Mvc/Services/IEmailSender.cs) with source code of sample web application with Identity in my previos comment. Pay attention, where the IEmailSender interface is located and how it works. It isn't a part of Identity libraries.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. This helps a ton, thank you! :)